# samsung s4 heat issues

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

my phone is a samsung galaxy s4 I9505

after a little use e.g. browsing, scrolling through the phone,  the top part of the phone gets pretty warm which is where the cpu is

the top part of the phone also gets quite warm when charging but the battery remains cold

in all instances the top part of the phone gets very warm

I have seen the display s4 s in a shop and they don't even get a little warm

is this a hardware problem, should I get a replacement

Answer (score 3):

Galaxy s4 has a lot of heating issue with both android 4.4.2 as well as android 5. But the temperature can be decreased if you follow some steps as described belowdecks the link:

http://www.androidpit.com/galaxy-s4-lollipop-problems-and-how-to-fix-them

Now if you have not updated the device and still it heats much then ask for refund. Despite being said all these I would suggest you not to go for s4 because it's     Not what you think of this 2014 flagship model.

- it lags too often.
- It's battery backup is very less (don't see 2600 mAh)
- it heats very much (temperature goes beyond 62 degrees) .

These are quite few problems , there are still lot of bugs too which will definitely let you ask for refund.

Here is a screenshot of what i mean.

[image]

Comment: Do you think if I got a replacement, it would be the same as this and have the same heat issues?

Comment: Yes , most probably it would have the same heating issue.

Comment: When you say temperature of phone goes beyond 62 degrees do you mean in Celsius or farenheit. .have you ever seen it get to 62?

Comment: It's in degree Celsius, I have also taken it's screenshot, but now i need to find it.

Comment: Sorry to keep disturbing you but could you please tell me which app you are using so I can compare with mine (exact name)

Comment: It's fine , i don't want you to believe me blindly https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en